# Iterate through CSV row in nodejs

Tags: node.js, csv, amazon-mws

I'm iterating through a CSV file `shipmentId.csv` and it seems like the function is reading each row, but the JSON file that I'm writing to is not appending. It's just writing the last API response. How do I append the JSON file to save the entire loop of API responses?

```
// read csv file
const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'shipmentId.csv');
fs.readFile(filePath, async (error, data) => {
  if (error) {
    return console.log('error reading file');
  }
  
  // parsedData = [{id, ShipmentId, ...}, {id, ...}, ...]
   const parsedData = await neatCsv(data);
   parsedData.map((rowObj) => {
    // rowObj = {id, ShipmentId, ...}
    let id = rowObj.ShipmentId;
    // console.log(id)
     

    (async function () {
         
      const mwsRequestData = {
        Version: '2010-10-01',
        Action: 'ListInboundShipmentItems',
        SellerId: config.SellerId,
        MWSAuthToken: config.MWSAuthToken,
        ShipmentId: id,
      };
    try {  
      let response = await mws.fulfillmentInboundShipment.search(mwsRequestData);
      if (response.status == 200) {
        throw new Error(`Unexpected status code ${response.status}, expected 200`);
      }
      console.log('response', response);
      // let data = JSON.stringify(response, null, 2);
      fs.writeFileSync('todo2.json', JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('That did not go well.')
    } 
    }());  
  });
});
```

Comment: There are multiple things wrong here: 1) `.map()` isn't async aware so it won't serialize the asynchronous operations inside the callback - Use a `for` loop instead inside a higher level `async` function and then you can serialize the asynchronous operations with `await`.  2) `fs.readFileSync()` replaces the entire file contents so you aren't appending data, you're overwriting with the last data so you need to either append or accumulate all the data and write it all at once when done.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by using `appendFileSync` instead of `writeFileSync`: I replaced this:

```
fs.writeFileSync('todo2.json', JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
```

by this:

```
fs.appendFileSync('todo2.json', JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
```

Comment: i thought it was the answer, but it was not what I was looking for. do you have suggestions?

Comment: I don't have a suggestion, sorry (but this solution looks completely reasonable). Still, I edited your answer a bit to make it sound more like an answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You are constantly rewriting the `todo2.json` file in each iteration of map.
Instead you could collect all data in an array and write it to a file outside the `parsedData.map()` or stream it into a file from inside the map.

You could gather references from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48442773/how-to-write-a-json-array-to-a-file-with-node-js-writestream)